# Not snapping to Guides in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, snapping, tolerance

I have a layout created with (layout)snapping on and set to snap to guides only.  I have a series of rectangles for my title block.  Depending on the information within the rectangles, I may need to adjust the length to fit all the information.  My problem is that the rectangle boundaries aren't snapping to the guides.  They easily snap to guides when using ArcMap.

Is anyone else having this issue?

I didn't see a way to adjust the tolerance for guide snapping, only for editing snapping.

Software: ArcGIS Pro 2.1.3

Comment: I am having this same issue. When I turn snapping on, the height and width of my rectangles snap to the guides when I drag them over but when I let go of the mouse they just slide back to the original position. This is getting very frustrating.I can manage to resize my rectangle title blocks by turning off snapping and resizing height, but when I try width it will not resize. This is not really a solution but may be a work-around until someone can provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've just be zooming in real far to make sure my rectangles are lined up with my guide... it's definitely annoying, but gets the job done!